# I cant install Sleepyhead under Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I am trying to install Sleepyhead following the tutorial

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11756055#post11756055

but I cant compile the src code`

```
horacio@horacio-ThinkPad-X201:~/sleepyhead$ make
cd sleepyhead/ && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/etc/home/horacio/sleepyhead/sleepyhead»
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DGIT_BRANCH=\"master\" -DGIT_REVISION=\"3b53d93\" -D_TTY_POSIX_ -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL -I/usr/include/qt4/QtXml -I/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/X11R6/include -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from mainwindow.h:19:0,
                 from main.cpp:24:
oximetry.h:17:28: fatal error: qextserialport.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
 #include <qextserialport.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/etc/home/horacio/sleepyhead/sleepyhead»
make: *** [sub-sleepyhead-make_default-ordered] Error 2
horacio@horacio-ThinkPad-X201:~/sleepyhead
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the little spanish I know I would assume you need to install the dependencies. It is missing qextserialport.h (https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/wiki/Downloads?tm=2  git clone https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/ )

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I have considered  a missing dependency but the qextserialport.h file is located in sleephead/3rdparty/qextserialport/src folder . I dont know why the compile process cant find the file

Answer (score 1):

What I did under ubuntu 14.10

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install git-core qt4-dev-tools libqt4-opengl-dev libqtwebkit-dev zlib1g-dev

sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5 libqt5serialport5-dev

sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev

git clone git://sleepyhead.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/sleepyhead/sleepyhead

cd sleepyhead

export QT_SELECT=qt5

qmake

make -j3
```

Hope that will help

Comment: This worked! No edits needed, compiled from git HEAD. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I successfully compiled sleepyhead a couple of months back, so I don't remember all the steps.  My system has the qextserialport package installed on it.  If I were you, I would load that package and see if that changes things.  The sleepyhead package needs to be fixed, but there are probably more important things to do...

Answer (score 0):

What helped here:

- Create a link to /usr/include/qt4/QtExtSerialPort

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/include/QtExtSerialPort /usr/include/qt4/QtExtSerialPort
  ```
- if qazip.h is missing, install libquazip0-dev

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libquazip0-dev
  ```

regards
thomas

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble building SleepyHead with qt5 (default on my ubuntu 13.10) but was able to build it with one code change and a soft link mentioned above using qt4 successfully. The following are the steps.

Note: This is on Ubuntu 13.10

```
apt-get install git qt4-dev-tools libqt4-opengl-dev libquazip0-dev libqextserialport-dev libqextserialport1
sudo ln -s /usr/include/QtExtSerialPort /usr/include/qt4/QtExtSerialPort
git clone git://sleepyhead.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/sleepyhead/sleepyhead
cd sleepyhead

edit sleepyhead/newprofile.h and add a line "#include <QUrl>" and save. Now do a qmake-qt4 followed by make

qmake-qt4
make
```